# How to increase maximum execution time in php

Tags: php, ini, execution-time

I want to increase *maximum execution time* in php , not by changing `php.ini` file.

I want to Increase it from my php file.

Is this possible?

Comment: use set_time_limit(n) where n is the time in seconds

Comment: This question has been downvoted and marked as duplicate yet it has a richer set of answers than said duplicate.

Comment: you might need to increase the max execution time for the server, too.

Comment: use ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); to get unlimited execution time. To Ignore user aborts and allow the script to run forever use ignore_user_abort(true);

Answer (score 555, accepted):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300'); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0'); // for infinite time of execution
```

Place this at the top of your PHP script and let your script loose!

Taken from [Increase PHP Script Execution Time Limit Using ini_set()](http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-script-execution-time-limit-ini_set)

Comment: works in windows but not in linux.

Comment: Works in Linux (php-5.2.10-1.el5.centos.rpm)

Comment: On PHP 7.0.22, when I set the time limit with `ini_set('max_execution_time', '7200');`, I don't understand why the script still runs at most 120 seconds and I get the error `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in`. Any idea?

Comment: This change only applies for the current running script? Or does the new maximum limit persists?

Comment: according to here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php, "The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending"

Comment: it should be noted that the web server also has timeout directive like Apaches [TimeOut](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#timeout) this is quoted from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) **" Your web server can have other timeout configurations that may also interrupt PHP execution. Apache has a Timeout directive and IIS has a CGI timeout function. Both default to 300 seconds. See your web server documentation for specific details. "**

Comment: What if time is setted like this: `ini_set('max_execution_time', '-1');` 
Is this similar to 0, that will be a infinite tiem of execution?

Answer (score 165):

use below statement if `safe_mode` is off

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 67):

Use the PHP function

```
void set_time_limit ( int $seconds )
```

The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.

> This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode. There is
>   no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing the time
>   limit in the php.ini.

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted as this is a perfectly formulated answer. Upvoted.

Answer (score 35):

You can try to [`set_time_limit(n)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). However, if your PHP setup is running in safe mode, you can *only* change it from the `php.ini` file.