# Set ini max_execution_time doesn't work

Tags: php, nginx

Before I use nginx and php-fpm, I used Apache, so when I wanted only one of my cron jobs to run without time execution limitation, I used these lines in my PHP code:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

but after I migrated from Apache to nginx, this code doesn't work. I know ways to change `nginx.conf` to increase maximum execution time.

But I want to handle this with php code. Is there a way?
I want to specify only one file that can run PHP code without time limitation.

Comment: I think you have to replace `set ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` with `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171132/how-to-increase-maximum-execution-time-in-php

Comment: @chevi sry i edit my question that was written problem in my question.

Comment: Consider using set_time_limit()

Comment: I guess it works, but nginx has it own timeouts (see nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html) so you have to adjust them too.

Comment: @alexeyten the problem is if i want change defalut value of timeout in nginx and increase it my problem will be solved but in other php files make security problems

Comment: You could change timeout for one separate location

Comment: @alexeyten you mean with nginx conf ?

Comment: Yes. And I don't any other ways.

Comment: @alexeyten ok tanx ;)

Answer (score 25):

**Try This:**

Increase PHP script execution time with **Nginx**

**You can follow the steps given below to increase the timeout value. PHP default is 30s. :**

### Changes in php.ini

If you want to change max execution time limit for php scripts from 30 seconds (default) to 300 seconds.

```
vim /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

Set…

```
max_execution_time = 300
```

In Apache, applications running PHP as a module above would have suffice. But in our case we need to make this change at 2 more places.

**Changes in PHP-FPM**

This is only needed if you have already un-commented request_terminate_timeout parameter before. It is commented by default, and takes value of max_execution_time found in php.ini

Edit…

```
vim /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Set…

```
request_terminate_timeout = 300
```

**Changes in Nginx Config**

To increase the time limit for example.com by

```
vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300; 
}
```

If you want to increase time-limit for all-sites on your server, you can edit main nginx.conf file:

```
vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Add following in http{..} section

```
http {
    #...
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300; 
    #...
}
```

**Reload PHP-FPM & Nginx**

Don’t forget to do this so that changes you have made will come into effect:

```
service php5-fpm reload
service nginx reload
```

**or try this**

```
fastcgi_send_timeout 50;
fastcgi_read_timeout 50;
```

fastcgi has it's own set of timeouts and checks to prevent it from stalling out on a locked up process.  They would kick in if you for instance set php's execuction time limit to 0 (unlimited) then accidentally created an infinite loop.  Or if you were running some other application besides PHP which didn't have any of it's own timeout protections and it failed.

Comment: for some reason i have max_execution_time set to 300 and haven't set fastcgi_read_timeout, the server was timing out before 300 secs as if fastcgi_read_timeout is not overwritten by max_execution_time (isn't this the expected behavior?). when i raised fastcgi_read_timeout to 300, it started to respect the 300s timeout. what did i misunderstand?

Answer (score 3):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

do this if **"Safe Mode"** is off

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Place this at the top of your PHP script and let your script loose!

***Note:*** if your PHP setup is running in safe mode, you can only change it from the php.ini file.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you have php-fpm and nginx "you can't" set this time only from PHP.

What you could do is a redirect with the parameters indicating you where to continue, but you must control the time that your script is running to avoid timeout.

If your process runs in a browser window, then do it with Javascript the redirect because the browser could limit the number of redirects... or do it with ajax.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can add **request_terminate_timeout = 300** to your server's php-fpm pool configuration if you are tried all of solutions here.