# How to increase request timeout for specific script php fpm

Tags: php, apache, fpm

I am using `laravel` with `php-fpm` and `apache` and i want to increase request timeout.

I tried `set_time_limit(0)` and `ini_set('max_execution_time')` but it not worked because i am using `php-fpm`.

When i add `timeout = 300` or `proxy_timeout = 300` on `httpd.conf` ( apache config ) problem solves But i want to do this on specific script.

Is there any solution for this problem?

**Edit**

Apache Version: 2.4.6

PHP: 5.6.31

OS: CentOS 7.2

Comment: You can't set a timeout for a specific script. I'll make a guess that you're doing a time-intensive task in this script, which you're triggering via browser - yes, that is absolutely a terrible decision. Look up [fastcgi_finish_request](http://www.php.net/fastcgi_finish_request) function and rework your logic so that you return a response to web server / client, but resume processing in the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change max execution time limit for php scripts.

```
vim /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

SET:

```
max_execution_time = 300
```

Changes in PHP-FPM

SET

```
request_terminate_timeout = 300
```

Article Source : [Set Max INI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658908/set-ini-max-execution-time-doesnt-work)

Comment: I want to set this for specific script not all

Comment: @SaeedVaziry got the same problem, did you find a way ?

Comment: @fmarrot no i didn't