# how do i solve the maximum execution time exceeded in php imap

Tags: php, imap

I'm facing problem with imap. Actually i m trying to fetch some mails whose subject words matches with keywords in my database. I m using an email id on which it works fine, but while using different email id's with same mails in it, it is showing maximum execution time of 30 sec exceeded. I also checked the imap settings in gmail, they are alright..

And also getting this error.. "Undefined property: stdClass::$subject"

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost",'root',"","project 6 sem");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
//else
  //echo "Database connected..</br>";
?>
<?php

function Reply($prikey,$seckey,$submit3)
{
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost",'root',"","project 6 sem");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
    echo $prikey;
    echo $seckey;

   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM data1 where pkey='$prikey' and skey='$seckey'");

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
       if($submit3 == "Positive")
       {
           $ans1 = $row['reply_yes'];

     //echo $ans1;
       }
       else if($submit3 == "Negative")
       {
           $ans1 =  $row['reply_no'];
     //echo $ans1;
       }
       echo "<br>";
       break;

    //header('location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  }
   mysqli_close($con);
   return $ans1;
}
?>
<?php
$submit1 = NULL;
$submit2 = NULL;
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    $submit1 = ($_POST['submit1']);
}
//echo $submit1;
if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
    $submit2 = ($_POST['submit2']);
}
if(isset($_POST['select']))
{
    $select = ($_POST['select']);
}

$cbody=0;
$subject=0;
$hostname= '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'xxxxx';
$password = 'XXXXX';
/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Tiriyo: ' . imap_last_error());
/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

$count = imap_num_msg($inbox);
$temp=array();
$m=0;
$a=0;
$sk=array();
$pk=array();
$subcount=0 ;
$subarray=array() ;
$msgcount=0;
$msgarray=array() ;
$ans1 = "";
$b=0;
  if($inbox)
  {
       $num = imap_num_msg($inbox);
       rsort($emails);
       $pk = array();

       foreach ($emails as $email_number)
      {
      $b++;
      echo "$b</br>";
         // ini_set('max_execution_time',50);
          $headers = imap_headerinfo($inbox, $email_number);    
          $sub_arr=explode(" ",$headers->subject);
          $count_sub=count($sub_arr);
          $pkey=array("Permission","permission",
                                          "Application","application",
                      "Complaint","complaint",
                                          "Enquiry","enquiry",
                      );
           $skey=array("lab","Lab","auditorium","Auditorium","IT Parking","leave");                                                   
          for($j=0;$j<$count_sub;$j++)
          {
                if($a==4)
                    break;
            for($r=0;$r<count($pkey);$r++)
            {       
                if($a==4)
                    break;
                  if($sub_arr[$j]==$pkey[$r])// Find the Primary key i.e from Subject
                  {
              $a++;
                          $sub=$headers->subject;
              $subarray[$subcount]=$headers->subject;
              $subcount+=1;
                          //echo "<b>$headers->subject</b></br>";
                          $message=imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1);
                          $msgarray[$msgcount]=imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1);
                          $body=explode(" ",$msgarray[$msgcount]);
              $msgcount+=1;
                          $count=count($body);
```

Comment: I think your problem is on line 177.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171132/how-to-increase-maximum-execution-time-in-php

Comment: To get any help with the "Undefined property" you'll need to post some code.

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER** You can change `max_execution_time` parameter in `php.ini` file. Standart is 30. If you have access you can change it to needed value.

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

**BUT** I don't think it is good idea (and also if you can't change your `php.ini` file).

Another way is to make php file, where you will get array of user's email. After that you will create `ajax` request, which will send each e-mail. So your script will work for only few seconds (or, possibly, ms), but many times. I think it is better (exactly if you can't edit `php.ini`, like in mine situation).

If you use this approach, this will allow you to get error's count, for example, and make ui more user friendly. You can track numbers of mails had already sent, for example.

I will add there simple example:

Script, which will get all e-mails and will be sending ajax requests:

```
foreach(email in emails) {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: "send_rent_receipts.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'mail='+email, // and other data
            success: function(data){
                count = count + 1;
                if(data == 'true')
                {   // add successfull sent
                    countSuccess = countSuccess + 1;
                }
                else
                {   // add error
                    arr.push(data); 
                    countErrors = countErrors + 1;
                }
                if(count == <?=$totalEntries;?>)
                {
                    $('#status').html('All mails had been sent!<br>Sent successfully: '+countSuccess+', Errors:  '+countErrors);
                    $("#status-image").attr( "src", "/images/thumb_up.png" );
                    for (key in arr) 
                    {
                        $('results').append(arr[key]+"<br>"); // handling errors
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#status').html('Process...<br><b>Total e-mail's: '+totalEntries+'</b><br>Sent successfully: '+countSuccess+', Errors: '+countErrors);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
<?
}
```

Script which will send 1 e-mail:

```
// send 1 e-mail
```

Simple :)

But, you can just change `max_execution_time` :)

Comment: I think the problem is not with max_execution time.. the problem why are the key works in my array matching for a mail and not for other in which both the mail id have same mails..

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the INI, you can set the setting in your script. This might be safer for a single script instead of changing it for all scripts on the server (as an INI change would).

```
<?php
    set_time_limit ( 0 ); //0 = unlimited
```

For more information : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: There really isn't enough information to answer that. Anytime you are connecting to an outside host you are at the mercy of that host. In this case you are at the mercy of Google/GMail. The server that holds the 2nd account may be having issues... the account could have 10x the number of emails (longer searching) etc.

Comment: Okk. Any solution to it..?? And one more thing it  was working fine before few days with any gmail id but now it is working only for one email id..