# More time to execute php script

Tags: php, timeout

Is there anyway to set timeout time with php?
 I have a script which is executing more time that my server allows to. How to change timeout time? Is it possible with php? Is it even possible?
 I can access my server settings only via cPanel.

Comment: I get this error:
504 Gateway Time-out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use set_time_limit() found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 0):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php or here: [How to increase maximum execution time in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171132/how-to-increase-maximum-execution-time-in-php)