# order of executing shell_exec in php

Tags: php, python

I want to execute 2 scripts: `s1` and `s2`. `s2` must be executed *after* `s1`.
The time of execution of `s1` is 2800 seconds, and I need to execute `s2` *after* `s1`. Should I put `sleep(3000)` in my php between them, or will the second one execute *automatically* after the first one?

I tried this:

```
exec('python s1 '); //time of execution is 2800s

sleep(3000); // i want to be sure that the first one is finished

shell_exec('php /home/Parik/s2.php');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) manual page:

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

In short, PHP will wait for your `python s1` command to finish before continuing.

Note that a execution time of 3000 seconds will most definitely time out without changing the default maximum execution time in the ini file. See [How to increase maximum execution time in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171132/how-to-increase-maximum-execution-time-in-php).