# About max execution timeout

Tags: php, laravel, server, httpresponse, max-execution-timeout

I have some question on server response `max execution timeout`.

If, I called server API to running something huge and not able to finish within time limit set in server `php.ini` `max_execution_time` config, will the process in server still continue to process? 
- if so, will it process endless? 
- if not, is the process stop immediately or canceling loop one by one and finish all process.

In my experience, when I receive  `max execution timeout` on local hosting, the data is already process.

So I not sure it is because it is stuck on response until timeout or server is continue running after throw `max execution timeout` exception.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your PHP code is like.

Usually the code execution will halt. You can alter this behaviour using [ignore_user_abort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php).

Comment: I checked my `php.ini`, it is disabled, but the final output is processed

Answer (score 1):

PHP interpreter runs scripts against php.ini configuration and checks max_execution_time = 500 and max_input_time = 500.

PHP doesn't continue to run the script after the max_execution_time. It's simply "kills" the script.

What can also happen, script starts a database query, normally query will run on database server until finished no-matter what happens to the script. Also you may get a Gateway Timeout coming from the web server, for Apache check httpd.conf and look for the setting Timeout.

If you need to run a script that takes time to execute, a lot more then the rest of your website, you should call a web page, PHP on server, fork a new process as a background executed script (the PHP part that takes lot of time), inform user via async status updates or sending an email that processing ended. You should not extend max_execution_time for all script just for one exception.

Comment: I checked my `php.ini`,` max_input_time=-1` and `max_execution_time=30`, so script is stop after 30 sec? I don know what will be affect when `max_input_time` set to unlimit

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't continue after the exception is thrown. It's simply cut when the time is up.

Anything before the time out is executed. If not designed especially to precent this.

Answer (score 0):

The process won't continue and stop immediately after the time limit set in server php.ini max_executiontime config has been reached then php throw a max execution timeout exception.

Here ([How to increase maximum execution time in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171132/how-to-increase-maximum-execution-time-in-php)) if you want to increase maximum execution time in php file.