# How to bypass maximum execution time in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I know this is an ugly idea, but how can I bypass this maximum execution error. I don't want to configure any .ini that I have read in some solutions.

I have this code to upload csv to sql database but this keeps me giving an error when uploading large files. Please help me revise my code guys

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $db = 'jeremy_db';

    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password) or die('Could not' .mysqli_error($con));

    mysqli_select_db($con, $db) or die ('Could not' .mysqli_error($con));

    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $c = 0;

    while(($csvdata = fgetcsv($handle,10000,","))!== FALSE){
        $sha1 = $csvdata[0];
        $vsdt = $csvdata[1];
        $trendx  = $csvdata[2];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO jeremy_table_trend (sha1,vsdt,trendx) VALUES ('$sha1','$vsdt','$trendx')";
        $query = mysqli_query($con , $sql);

        $c = $c+1;
    }
    if($query){
        echo "success"; 
    }
    else { 
        echo "error";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you can't. That's why you have the configuration file to alter.

Comment: There is no way to bypass because this is basically php setting. So you have to reconfigure php.ini file anyway.

Comment: "I don't want to edit any ini."
Good luck!

Comment: "I don't want to edit any ini." Good luck! - oops didn't configure any .ini but working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

add this line to your code

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes //whatever you want
```

Taken from [How to increase maximum execution time in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171132/how-to-increase-maximum-execution-time-in-php)

Comment: OP is against altering the config settings. ;)

Comment: if its helpful to you than accept the answer so other use it

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi What `ini_set('varName', 'varValue')` does is essentially override the INI config for the duration of the PHP script's execution. See the PHP documentation for more info. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: @Will you need to read the question properly. OP is definitely confused. OP phrased the question as looking for ways to increase execution time without altering settings. This answer is clearly altering the settings just in a different way

Comment: But it doesn't notify me the success when the uploading is done

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi ` increase execution time without  altering settings.` in `.ini file` not in `php script`

Answer (score 0):

Executing insert statements in the loop is expensive. You can try dumping the csv file directly into MySQL, that will take relatively lesser execution time.

[Refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127529/mysql-import-data-from-csv-using-load-data-infile)