# Insert bulk of models to the database

Tags: php, excel, laravel, collections, model

I built a laravel app that reads excel files as a `collection` using `laravel-excel` and store the data into the database after looping over the result, each row represents one model so inside the loop I create a new model, assign the attributes and save the model and so on till the rows are finished.

This technique works well when I read small excel files (less than 2000 rows) but when I deal with large excel files (13000 rows or more) the app starting to crash so I set the `max_execution_time=300` in `php.ini` but this also didn't help.

Any idea or technique to make this works.

Thanx

Comment: I receive `504 Gateway Time-out` when reading large files

Comment: Did you restart your server after changing the `php.ini` file? You might have to increase your `max_execution_time`. If it's only a one time insert then you can make `max_execution_time=0` for infinite length to complete the insert and change it back afterwards. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171132/how-to-increase-maximum-execution-time-in-php

Comment: Yes I restarted the server

Comment: in the server error log: upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream request: POST /process HTTP/2.0, upstream: php7.2-fpm.sock

Comment: Can you see this https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html

Comment: Laravel chunk reading doesn't work because i read the excel file into a collection not to a model directly