# Run php block for specific amount of time

Tags: php, time

I am trying to write a basic web scraper in php. I am having an issue where if the server times out due to the parser taking too long then it deletes the content in my db. Is there a way to specify I want to run my parsing block for, say, 5 minutes? I have tried the set_time_limit(n) function before starting the loop, but setting set_time_limit(1) the script keeps running.

Comment: I think you should check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171132/how-to-increase-maximum-execution-time-in-php

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is running in safe mode, the only way is in the php.ini file. Or turn off safe mode and change the limit as follows:

`void set_time_limit ( int $seconds )`

or

`set_time_limit(300);
// 300seconds are 5 minutes`

I hope this helps you