# Maximum execution time exceed in long polling

Tags: php, ajax, telegram-bot, long-polling, php-telegram-bot

I developed a telegram bot that posts the score of the cricket match in the telegram group. As you know, the score will keep changing within time, So I need to send the message when only the score is updated. To achieve this, I'm using the long-polling method (hit the API after every 10 seconds to get the updated score) but at one time, the maximum execution time is exceeded. So what is the best way to achieve this?

```
<?php
session_start();

$token = 'xyz';
$group_name = 'xyz';

while(true){

    $ipl = file_get_contents('https://cricket-api.vercel.app/cri.php?url=https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scores/38708/rocks-vs-war-pool-d-csa-provincial-t20-cup-2021');  

    $ipl_data = json_decode($ipl, true);
    $current_score = $ipl_data['livescore']['current'];

    $_SESSION["score"] =  $current_score;

    if($_SESSION["score"] != $current_score){
        $bot = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$group_name}&text={$current_score}";
        $hit = file_get_contents($bot);    
    }
    sleep(10);    
}
?>
```

Comment: you are exceeding the time limit by your self. you can increase the limit https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: I doubt if that would be considered a reliable way

Comment: Run the code as a CRON job using the PHP CLI then there are no execution time limits

Comment: You also did not implement any mechanism for remembering the last score so you only make updates when the score has changed?

Comment: Does this answers your question? [How to increase maximum execution time in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171132/how-to-increase-maximum-execution-time-in-php)

Comment: Let me update the code so you can see what I have achieved so far. You can check now @RiggsFolly

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: So where is the `session_start()` in this code?

Comment: I forgot to add here! But it is present in the script

Comment: I'm sure I did something silly or have I done it correctly?

Comment: Did you able to figure out what have I done wrong? the solution to compare the new value retrieved from an API call against the previously retrieved value?

Comment: The problem has been fixed! here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69437889/store-api-previous-value-and-compare-with-new-one/69438171#69438171